# Using UIPanGesture store the location of the image moved to new location in the UIView in Objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipangesturerecognizer

I am moving UIImage in a view. Now when the image is moved to new position I want to keep that image in that position and store that in an array. How can I achieve this ?

The code for moving image using pan gesture is :-

```
- (void) handlePan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recogniser {
    CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:_backImage];

    //Only allow movement up to within 100 pixels of the right bound of the screen
    if (point.x < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 100) {

        CGRect newframe = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, smallImageViewWidth, smallImageViewHeight);
        _centreImage.frame = newframe;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep one global array in your VC and named that

NSMutableArray *arrImagePositions = [NSMutableArray array];

IN your method you can store that location in this array

```
- (void) handlePan: (UIPanGestureRecognizer *) recognizer
{

   CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:_backImage];

   //Only allow movement up to within 100 pixels of the right bound of the screen
   if (point.x < [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 100) {

    CGRect newframe = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, smallImageViewWidth, smallImageViewHeight);
    _centreImage.frame = newframe;

    //store all location where you moved your image in array 
       if(gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){
           [arrImagePositions addObject: newframe];
       //store here in your array.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help... If you found answer is helpful then please accept for others.  :)